# Cannot install anything on Windows 10: "Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, matlab, visual-c++

I'm trying to install Matlab, but the culprit is probably Visual C++ Redistributable (which Matlab is installing along the way).

When I run the setup, every time it fails with:

> Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

I already searched for a solution, and every article suggests to uninstall security updates *which I don't have*! Many articles are from a couple years ago, while I recently downloaded the Windows ISO and installed it. Could it be that those updates are already installed in my system, but I cannot uninstall them?

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to install Matlab R2016a. I'm posting what I did in case anyone in the future needs this.

The culprit is Visual C++ Redistributable 2008, which Matlab wants to install at all costs (even though I wasn't even going to use it). I downloaded from the Microsoft website all Visual C++ versions, and all except the last one (2015 version) refused to install (same error).

I unpacked Matlab's setup.exe and inside the `bin` directory I found the Visual C++ installer. There were two copies:

- `bin\vcredist_x64.exe`
- `bin\vc90\vcredist_x64.exe`

The latter is the one that was being executed, so I replaced it with the last version (I also had to rename the file in order to replace the Matlab's one).

Now the install went through, but when starting Matlab the Visual C++ 2008 kept popping up asking to install. So I went into Matlab's `bin` directory (for me it was `C:\Program Files\Matlab\bin`) and replaced `vcredist_x64.exe` (which somehow Matlab had overwritten with its copy) with a custom executable which I compiled to do nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem installing E-Prime 2.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise...Same culprit, it seems; same error code. Since I'm not super enough to unpack or compile EXEs (yeah, probably easier than I think), I needed a different solution, and [this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/error-error-997-while-installing-microsoft-visual/60a4f08e-a740-475d-8858-3435b2784b01?auth=1) worked for me:

> In short: Rename the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18` to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18_old`
>
> During successful installation of KB3045318 this folder is created again, automatically.
>
> At the end, I copied the missing files from the original folder to the new folder.

Truth be told, I saw another odd error ("`support\vc2008 sp1 vcredist_x86.exe copy failed: lasterror=5`") during installation of E-Prime, but I was able to dismiss it and complete installation successfully.  I also haven't "copied the missing files from the original folder..." because I don't know what purpose they serve, but maybe I should?  No explosions so far anyway. What counts is that I now have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable 9.0.30729.6161 (both x64 and x86 versions) installed, and I couldn't seem to do it any other way. This solution was very simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an [article](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Install-Failure-Error-997-Overlapped-I-O-operation-is-in-progress.html) dated 5th May 2016 and it has couple of options to solve your issue:

1. Install [Microsoft hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000988)
2. Remove the updates **KB2918614**, **KB3072630**, **KB3000988** and **KB3008627** do reboot and try installing Matlab again
3. Edit registry as the mentioned above tutorials suggests, but in a bit other way. You should probably delete everything what's associated with Matlab, reboot and then try installing once again.

> The article I'm referring to is related to Autodesk software, but there is a high probability that it could be a universal fix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried all the options but unfortunately none worked. Those updated aren't listed among the installed ones. I have 5 updates installed and all start with **KB31**.

Comment: @rubik Have you tried to remove all of the 5 updates you currently have?

Comment: Yes, but only one can be uninstalled. The other ones do not have this option...

Comment: @rubik Have you tried to boot into safe mode and uninstall the updates? ``Run``->``msconfig``->``Boot``->``Safe boot``->``Ok``->``Restart``

Comment: Nothing... Thanks anyway, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @rubik You mean you cannot uninstall updates even in the safe mode? This cannot be true. Do you get any type of errors?
Also it would help if you'd specify exactly what updates do you have already installed (by naming them) and what version of matlab you're trying to install as well as on what windows 10 version you're running.

Comment: Oh no, I did uninstall the updates, but the error persisted. I think I got it working by swapping files. I'll post what I did soon.